# Overlaying two gridviews

Tags: android, android-layout

I am attempting to make a simple pairs memory game for Android.

I have attempted to place two grid views over each other, with the top gridview 'covering' the contents of the bottom gridview. So the top gridview is obscuring the icons underneath, and when a tile in the top gridview is pressed, it exposes the icon underneath.

Presently, however, only the bottom gridview shows (grid_view_bottom) and I cannot figure out why. Even when I comment out the bottom gridview code, the top gridview does not show up.

Any help world be appreciated.

In the onCreate method, I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    gridViewTop = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view_top);
    gridViewBottom = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view_bottom);
    gridViewTop.setNumColumns(mColumns);
    gridViewBottom.setNumColumns(mColumns);
    adapterBottom = new ImageAdapter(this, mColumns, mRows);
    adapterTop = new TopImageAdapter(this, mColumns, mRows);

    gridViewTop.setAdapter(adapterTop);
    gridViewBottom.setAdapter(adapterBottom);   
    gridViewTop.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

The activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/info"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:numColumns="6"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" ></GridView>

 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/info"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:numColumns="6"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"></GridView>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimens_32"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textSize="22sp"></TextView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

TopImageAdapter.java

```
public class TopImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private int mColumns;
private int mRows;
private int mFrontImage = R.drawable.front;

public TopImageAdapter(Context context, int cols, int rows) {
    mContext = context;
    mColumns = cols;
    mRows = rows;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mFrontImage));
        int width = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - 10;
        int height = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - 170;
        int scaleX = width / mColumns;
        int scaleY = height / mRows;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(scaleX, scaleY));
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    }

    return imageView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

}
```

bottom image adapter (ImageAdapter.java)

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private int mColumns;
private int mRows;
private int mTotalViews;
private Integer[] mThumbIds = { array of images };
private ArrayList<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private boolean[] enabledViews;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, int cols, int rows) {
    mContext = c;
    mColumns = cols;
    mRows = rows;
    mTotalViews = cols * rows;
    enabledViews = new boolean[mTotalViews];
    Arrays.fill(enabledViews, Boolean.TRUE);
    populateList();
}

private void populateList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mTotalViews / 2; j++) {
            collection.add(mThumbIds[j]);
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(collection);
}

public void setEnabled(boolean flag, int position) {
    enabledViews[position] = flag;
}

public int getItemResourceId(int position) {
    return collection.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return collection.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return collection.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable( collection.get(position)));
        int width = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - 10;
        int height = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - 170;
        int scaleX = width / mColumns;
        int scaleY = height / mRows;
        imageView
                .setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(scaleX, scaleY));
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    }
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. Not only are their issues with placing 2 scrollable views on top of each other but I don't think the layering works they way you are assuming - i.e. this notion that you can "flip over" a tile on top to show one on the bottom. Why can't you use one grid view and animate onClick to show something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in TopImageAdapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

is your problem, you need to return the size of your collection displayed at the bottomGridView. 
But i would suggest using just one GridView and alter the displayed images at an onClickEvent... using to GridViews is not really a good idea!

Comment: I initially wanted to use just the one gridview, but I was having trouble animating between showing the "underneath" icon smoothly.  I could fade the top tile out, but the underlying icon would just "snap" into focus. Your solution to my problem is correct, but I am going to try and make this more efficient. Thank you for your time.